# Remove the comment out part of BTEQ file with shell script

Tags: shell

I am new to shell script, i want to remove comment out part from BTEQ file with shell script

my BTEQ file contain

```
/*
***********************************************************
 my comment out part start 
 some more content
**********************************************************
*/
select * from abc 
/*****query description********************/
DELETE name from abc;
/*****query description********************/
 create table name
/*****query description********************/
```

i want the output as below in same BTEQ

```
select * from abc 
DELETE name from abc;
create table name
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [perl-regular-expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions), with greedy substitution(`.*?`)

```
$ perl -p0 -e 's#/\*.*?\*/##sg' file | perl -lane "print if /\S/"
select * from abc
DELETE name from abc;
 create table name
```

Comment: Hi Inian thank you for helping me, but this is not work because in my BTEQ there is multiple query like select,insert,update. can you please suggest some generic solution

Comment: @Code_rocks: What error are you getting. The above solution is generic by itself and not dependent any factors

Comment: @Code_rocks: my solution works for your latest update also with the 'create' statement

Comment: Hi Inian : can you plz help me if the line is commented out with ( eg  create table name --this is create table.) now i want to remove ("--this is create table")

Comment: Make an attempt with the answer provided and ask it as a new question. Answering it here will be beyond the scope of current question.